# Google Map API V3 not working inside polymer-element

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3, polymer

I created polymer-element and add Google Map in it. It works correctly if i write code of polymer-element direct into main file where i want to use it but if i keep its code in separate file and use it by importing then it gives following error in console:

> Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write
>   into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless
>   it is explicitly opened.

here is code of my-map.html file:

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
<polymer-element name="my-map">
        <template>
            <style type="text/css">
            :host{
                display: block;
            }
                #mapCanvas {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
          }
            </style>
            <div id="mapCanvas"></div>
        </template>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            Polymer({
                map:null,
                ready:function(){

                    this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.$.mapCanvas, {
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(41, -91),
                    disableDefaultUI: true,
                    zoom: 5
                     });
                }
            });
        </script>
    </polymer-element>
```

and this is code of main file index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Map</title>

    <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="my-map.html">
</head>
<body>
<my-map style="height:500px,width:500px;"></my-map>
</body>
</html>
```

where is problem?
if i write code of my-map.html file in index.html file then it work perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rough file structure:

- file: index.html
- file: my-map.html
- directory: bower_components/

  - directory: core-component-page/...
  - directory: polymer/...
  - directory: webcomponentsjs/...

It seems that google-maps failed to build up a map onto a polymer element when google-maps lib is included on top of definition of a polymer-element there can be one/several reasons to blame for this. But there are at least two solutions that work for me.

**First solution**

Try to exclude google-maps lib from your polymer element and include it into your index.html file:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Map</title>
    <!-- include google maps lib into your main index.html file -->
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="my-map.html">
</head>
<body>
    <my-map width="500px" height="500px"></my-map>
</body>
</html>
```

Polymer-element(my-map.html):

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<polymer-element name="my-map" attributes="width height">
    <template>
        <style type="text/css">
            :host{
                display: block;
            }
            #mapCanvas {
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px;
            }
        </style>
        <div id="mapCanvas" style="width:{{width}};height:{{height}}"></div>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            map:null,
            width: '100px',// default width
            height: '100px',// default height
            ready:function(){

                // map canvas lies within shadow-dom so it not accessible by ordinary *querySelector*, *querySelectorAll* or *getElementById* methods but this is a way: this.$.mapCanvas 
                this.map = new google.maps.Map(
                                this.$.mapCanvas,
                                { center: new google.maps.LatLng(41, -91),
                                  disableDefaultUI: true,
                                  zoom: 5
                                }
                );
            }
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

**Second solution:**

Try to use callback param of google maps lib(url-part: *&callback=callback*) and include google maps lib into the definition of the polymer element:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Map</title>
    <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="my-map.html">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- use default width/height -->
    <my-map></my-map>
</body>
</html>
```

Polymer-element(my-map.html):

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<polymer-element name="my-map" attributes="width height">
    <template>
        <style type="text/css">
            :host{
                display: block;
            }
            #mapCanvas {
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px;
            }
        </style>
        <div id="mapCanvas" style="width:{{width}};height:{{height}}"></div>
    </template>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&callback=callback"></script>
    <script>

        // use IIFE to encapsulate all defined variables to prevent them from being assigned to window object unintentionally
        (function(){

            var googleMapsReady = false;

            var myMapPolymer;
            var htmlCanvasMap;

            function callback(){

                googleMapsReady = true;

                if(htmlCanvasMap){
                    buildUpMap(htmlCanvasMap);
                }

            }
            // !!! unfortunately you have to assign callback function to window object
            // because this function has to be accessible globally  otherwise google maps lib will not find it and throws an error
            window.callback = callback;

            // function to show a google map on your site that takes a html element on which a map should be shown
            function buildUpMap(htmlmap){

                var map = new google.maps.Map(
                                    htmlmap,
                                    { center: new google.maps.LatLng(38, -91),
                                      disableDefaultUI: true,
                                      zoom: 8
                                    }
                );

                // at last assign google map object as property to polymer element
                myMapPolymer.map = map;

            }

            // polymer element code definition
            Polymer({
                map:null,
                width: '100px',// default width
                height: '100px',// default height
                ready:function(){

                    myMapPolymer = this;

                    // assign map canvas(div) to varible in order to use it for building up a map, 
                    htmlCanvasMap = this.$.mapCanvas;

                    if(googleMapsReady){
                        buildUpMap(htmlCanvasMap);
                    }

                }
            });

        })();

    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

At the second solution there are still opportunities to assign an initialized  google map object as property to a polymer element:

- variable *googleMapsReady* is set when google maps is loaded and ready to be used this is checked within *Polymer.ready* function.
- otherwise if *Polymer.ready* is called before *callback* then variable *htmlCanvasMap* is assigned and therefore *true* when checked within *callback* function.

Hope this helps.

Comment: at the second example there has been an issue because of assessing a div element that lies within shadow dom, second example is better now ;)